# WPF datagrid CellEditEnding event as routed event handler

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have created a WPF datagrid and used that in windows form using Element Host. I want to register the CellEditEnding event of WPF datagrid so that i can attach this event at windows form and fire it.
can anyone please help me by providing some solution?

Thanks
Vishal